# Selecting an element in an iframe which is dynamically created by external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a gallery that opens a modal window when clicked on photo. There is a div *#sbox-content* which is empty and when the photo is clicked, external script dynamically appends an *iframe* to this div.

**I need to select *h2* element inside this *iframe* after it fully loads.**

What I've tried so far (changing color only to see if it was selected correctly):

```
jQuery(document.body).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'iframe', function() {
    jQuery('h2.item-title').css({
        color: '#FF0000'
    })
});
```

and:

```
jQuery('iframe').load(function() {
    jQuery('h2.item-title').css({
        color: '#FF0000'
    })
});
```

and:

```
jQuery('iframe').load(function() {
    jQuery(this).contents().find('h2.item-title').css({
        color: '#FF0000'
    })
});
```

Nothing works...
Am I doing something wrong, or is the whole approach just not right?

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).on("load", "iframe", function...`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).on('load','iframe',function() {
    jQuery(this).find('h2.item-title').css({
        color: '#FF0000'
    })
}).load();
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, still nothing.

Comment: I think something wrong with h2. Do you have <h2 class="item-title"> or inside h2 the item-title class is there ???

Comment: Yeah, I've got <h2 class="item-title">. But it doesn't work even with find('h2'). I think that it has something to do with the fact that iframe doesn't exist in the DOM until the photo is clicked and jQuery(document).on('load', 'iframe'... is't helping here

Comment: As I thought: jQuery(document).on('load','iframe',function() {console.log('iframe loaded');}); doesn't work.

Comment: and ofcourse you should have bind these functions within the document.ready funciton....

Comment: Ofcourse, it's in document.ready function since the beginning.

Comment: I've recreated the problem online. If you'd be so kind, could you take a look at the edited part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that uses javascript (no library).

**Edit**

```
var newInterval;

newInterval = setInterval(function(){

if(typeof document.getElementById('sbox-content') != 'undefined' && document.getElementById('sbox-content') != null){

clearInterval(newInterval);

document.getElementById('sbox-content').onclick = function(){

checkifIframeExists();

}

}

},2000);
```

If there is only 1 iframe inside div#sbox-content and when the DOM is loaded

```
function checkifIframeExists(){

iframe_ = document.getElementById('sbox-content').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

iframe_.onload = function(){

if(this.contentDocument){ response = this.contentDocument; }else{ response = this.contentWindow.document; }

//So, with the above code we already have the content of the loaded iframe 

h2els = response.getElementsByTagName('h2');

if(h2els.length==1){

//now we are setting/changing the first h2 element's text color

h2els[0].style.color = '#FF0000';

}else{

//or if there is more than one h2 element, we loop through all the h2 elements and find the one with class 'item-title' and changing its color

for(var i=0;i<h2els.length;i++){

if(h2els[i].className == 'item-title'){

h2els[i].style.color = '#FF0000';

}

}

}

}
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned iframe doesn't even exist in the DOM. It's dynamically added by the external gallery plugin, which I can't modify. And when iframe is added to the DOM, it still doesn't have an id. Not even a class. But it always appends to the div #sbox-content

Comment: @zorza, is there only 1 iframe inside div #sbox-content?

Comment: yes, only one, but important thing is that the content inside the iframe may change (by navigating through photos with nex/prev buttons inside iframe).

Comment: But you are only targeting h2 element inside that iframe, don't you?

And that iframe is called whenever one of those photos is clicked, isn't it? And do you have any live example of what you are doing?

Comment: I've recteated the problem online. Please see the edited version of the question.

Comment: Just did. Doesn't work... Console response: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: This is due to the fact that the div with the id 'sbox-content' is added dynamically (when one of those photos is clicked), I suppose. That's why my script can't find that div and when you use this script on document onload it returns null.
You should call my script whenever one of those photos is clicked

Comment: Exactly. That is the whole point. But how to do this given that the plugin which opens the popup is an external script I must not access?

Comment: You should add a script on DOM onload which will check every say 2 or 3 seconds whether the div#sbox-content exists and if it does than assign a click event to it.